# MVVM xamarin android call http multiple time

Tags: android, http, xamarin, mvvm

we have an app under xamarin android who call some api in http in c#
we used MVVM inside this project.

The last change in this app call a new api and we notice that SOMETIMES for one call http the request is send 5 times at same time, same second, same millisecond ..

this call http, create a new record inside a backend and we see this because the record is duplicate multiple time ..

I've try to reproduce this case actually but i can't arrive..

here is it some code of the viewModel:

[image]

And this method is call on a fragment like this:
[image]

Any idea about how to solve this or reproduce this case would be appreceted
I'm not sure but i think as the viewModel is each time create with Vm = new ...
Perhpas the method is call many times ..

How to see if the viewModel exist several time or not ?

thanks for your time

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: What does `App.HttpService.Get` do? The issue must be in there?

Comment: Hello, sorry for copy image, but each time i copy pasta the code it's not well align and not really lisible ... the app.httpService.get is the class who manage the call http -> post / get / ... i try to reproduce this case but actually i can't ...it's so strange ! Thanks for idea , suggestion and so on ..